# Proving that $\mathbb{Q}$ adjoin the square root of every prime is an infinite extension

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

How would one show that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2, \sqrt3,...,\sqrt{p_n},...)]=\infty$? I know that we want to show there is no finite basis over the rationals, but I'm not sure how one would determine that such a basis does not exist.

Comment: Isn't it enough that there are infinitely many primes? Maybe I've misunderstood this question.

Comment: See e.g.  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1609061/300700

Answer (score 1):

Kummer theory tells us that as $ 2$, $3,\ldots,{p_n}$
generate a subgroup of order $2^n$ in $\Bbb Q^*/(\Bbb Q^*)^2$ then the
extension field $K_n=\Bbb Q(\sqrt2,\ldots,\sqrt {p_n})$ has degree $2^n$
over $\Bbb Q$. So your field contains subfields of arbitrarily large degree
over $\Bbb Q$.