# Proof with Galois theory that $K(\sqrt \alpha) = K(\sqrt \beta)$ if and only if it exists $\gamma$ with $\alpha = \gamma^2\beta$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, galois-extensions

Let E/K be a field extension, $1+1\neq0$ in K and $\alpha$, $\beta \in K^x=\{a \in K |\, \exists \, b: ab = ba =1\}$.

Proof with **Galois theory**: $K(\sqrt \alpha) = K(\sqrt \beta) \Leftrightarrow \exists \, \gamma \in K^x : \alpha = \gamma^2\beta$

---

Got so far that $\sqrt \alpha, \sqrt \beta \notin K \Rightarrow [K(\sqrt \alpha):K]= 2 =[K(\sqrt \beta):K] \overset{char(K) \neq 2}\Rightarrow K(\sqrt \alpha), K(\sqrt \beta)$ are galois.

Answer (score 2):

$\implies$: Assuming $K(\sqrt\alpha) = K(\sqrt\beta)$.

If $\sqrt\alpha = x\in K$, then $K(\sqrt\alpha) = K$, so we have $\sqrt\beta\in K$. Set $\gamma = \frac{\sqrt\alpha}{\sqrt\beta}$ and we're done.

Otherwise, we have $\sqrt\alpha\in K(\sqrt\beta)$. In other words, there are $x, y\in K$ such that
$$
\sqrt\alpha = x + y\sqrt\beta\\
\alpha = x^2 + \beta y^2 + 2xy\sqrt\beta
$$
From this we can deduce that $2xy = 0$, which because $1+1\neq 0$ gives us $xy = 0$, meaning either $x = 0$ or $y = 0$. However, $\sqrt\alpha\notin K$ implies $y\neq 0$, so we must have $x = 0$. Set $\gamma = y$, and we're done.

$\Longleftarrow\,$: Assuming $\alpha = \gamma^2\beta$.

We have $\sqrt\alpha = \gamma\sqrt\beta \in K(\sqrt\beta)$ and $\sqrt\beta = \sqrt\alpha/\gamma\in K(\sqrt\alpha)$, meaning the two fields must be the same.

Comment: The solution is absolutely right and I've solved the problem already that way. But I wanted to come up with a solution in which Galois theory would be applied.

Comment: @Zorro_C If you've done this already, that's the kind of thing you would want to put in the question post so that people don't spend time and effort duplicating your work.

Comment: Sorry, but I have mentioned in every line, also in the title, that I like to get a solution with application of Galois theory

Comment: What do you mean by "application of Galois theory".? If you admit that Kummer theory (see any text book) is contained in Galois theory, then you can apply it directly. For a summary of Kummer theory, see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1609061/300700