# Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{11}) / \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

**The question**:

> *Determine the Galois group of $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{11}) / \mathbb{Q}$ and how it works on $\alpha = \sqrt{6 + \sqrt{11}} \to a\sqrt{2} + b\sqrt{11}$.*

I'm not sure if I'm approaching this correctly and how to check the way it works on $\alpha$.

**My attempt**:

$K$ is the splitting field of the polynomial $(X^2 - 2)(X^2 -11)$.Then it is the splitting field of a separable polynomial, thus it is a Galois extension. It is trivial that $[K : \mathbb{Q}] = 4$, so the Galois group has order 4.

Also, since $K$ is a splitting field, the action is transitive so we have a group of order 4 that is a subgroup of $S_4$. Now, I've tried looking at the subgroups of order 4 of $S_4$ but I haven't really been able to see what group the Galois group now is. How do I find this group?

Comment: See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113689/11619) and in particular [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/150744/11619).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Galois group is $\cong\Bbb Z/2\times \Bbb Z/2$, its generators are $\sigma, \tau$, commuting field isomorphisms of order two with:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sigma\sqrt 2 &= -\sqrt 2\ ,\\ 
\sigma\sqrt {11} &= +\sqrt {11}\ ,\\[2mm] 
\tau\sqrt 2 &= +\sqrt 2\ ,\\ 
\tau\sqrt {11} &= -\sqrt {11}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The elements of the Galois group are thus $1, \sigma,\tau,\sigma\tau$.

The complicated given element can be rewritten
$$
\sqrt {6+\sqrt{11}}
=
\frac 1{\sqrt 2}\cdot \sqrt {12+2\sqrt{11}}
=\pm\frac 1{\sqrt 2}(1+\sqrt {11})\ ,
$$
and it should be clear how $\sigma,\tau$ act on it.

Answer (score 2):

We have the property that if $w$ is a root of the polynomial, then so is $-w$. Therefore, the Galois group is a subgroup of $D_8$. Since it has $4$ elements, it must be $V_4$ instead of $C_4$.

The $4$ elements are just switching $\sqrt2 \leftrightarrow -\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt{11} \leftrightarrow -\sqrt{11}$.

Comment: Alternatively, $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2, \sqrt 11)/\Bbb Q$ is clearly a degree-4 extension, so the Galois group has four elements. It also clearly has (at least) two distinct degree-2 subextensions, so the Galois group has at least two proper, non-trivial subgroups. Thus $V_4$ instead of $C_4$.

Comment: Ok I understand why it is $V_4$. But I don't get what all 4 automorphisms are: is there one that sends $\sqrt{2}$ to $\sqrt{11}$? Because there should be right?

Comment: @xzeo No, there shouldn't. $\sqrt2\mapsto\sqrt 11$ doesn't keep $\Bbb Q$ fixed, since it also sends $2 = (\sqrt2)^2\mapsto (\sqrt{11})^2 = 11$. Not that it's even an automorphism. No, there's the trivial automorphism, then there is the one that sends $\sqrt2\mapsto -\sqrt2$, there is the one that sends $\sqrt{11}\mapsto-\sqrt{11}$, and then finally it's the one that does both at the same time.

Comment: So the action is not transitive on the roots of the polynomial which I constructed the splitting field for? I thought it would be. Edit: just noticed that the polynomial has to be irreducible.